# Could not cast value of type 'MyPlugin.ActivateOtpViewController' to 'MyPlugin.ActivateOtpViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

Currently I am trying to create unit tests for our project which I refer to as "MyPlugin". There, I want to instantiate a View Controller in order to test its functions:

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

@testable import MyPlugin

class ActivateOtpViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut : ActivateOtpViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.assets)
        sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ActivateOTPViewController") as! ActivateOtpViewController
        sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

However my test fails to instantiate the View Controller. When I try to debug it following error message appears

```
Could not cast value of type 'MyPlugin.ActivateOtpViewController' 
(0x1021296d8) to 'MyPlugin.ActivateOtpViewController' (0x1328f35b8).
```

A colleague said that I might have two copiess of `MyPlugin` inside my test target but I can't happen to find the second copy within my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

use_frameworks!
target "MyPlugin_Example" do
    pod 'SwiftLint', '0.32.0'
    pod 'MyPlugin', :path => '../'
end

target "MyPlugin_Tests" do
    inherit! :complete
    pod 'MyPlugin', :path => '../'
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try commenting out `pod 'MyPlugin', :path => '../'` in `MyPlugin_Tests` you already have it as a part of your main target `MyPlugin_Example` and you anyway import module using `@testable import MyPlugin` so I believe `MyPlugin` should be available to you in Test target as well

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried commenting this line and ran ```pod update```. But then ```No such module 'MyPlugin'``` appears next to the import statement.

Comment: remove `@testable import MyPlugin` and use `@testable import MyPlugin_Example`

Comment: ```MyPlugin_Example``` couldn't be found. But ```Pods_C24CashReserve_Example``` was found. However, importing this module leads to ```Use of undeclared type 'ActivateOtpViewController'```.